# Registering a file in model.module.ts

Tags: angular

I am just reading and following an Angular 6 book and I have learned how to register classes but this one highlighted in this image below I didn't understand the syntax and why is it different. Can someone explain?
I also copy pasted the explanation from the book but still I didn't understand.

> It also adds a providers entry for the RestDataSource class, which has
>   been used only as a substitute for the StaticDataSource class in
>   earlier chapters. Since the AuthService class has a RestDataSource
>   constructor parameter, it needs its own entry in the module.

(Page 174).

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  providers: [ProductRepository, StaticDataSource, Cart, Order, OrderRepository, {provide: StaticDataSource, useClass: RestDataSource},
    RestDataSource, AuthService]
})
export class ModelModule { }
```

[image]

Comment: To me it's just that whenever you inject `StaticDataSource` in a component's constructor, it will instead use the `RestDataSoruce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the StaticDataSource provider will use instead the RestDataSource Class. Most of the time it is used to mock a Class or a value (if you'd have used `useValue` instead of `useClass`).

When the provider is only declared as a variable it's kind of a shortcut of `{provide: ProductRepository, useClass: ProductRepository}`